# Tunneling Http traffic from A to B using SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, http, forwarding

I am very new to networking and trying to understand SSH.

I have this setup

Device `A` : serving web app on a static `192.X.X.X`

Device`B` : can access the web app through `192.X.X.X`

Device `C`: connected to `B` but on a different network `10.X.X.X`, can only SSH to `B`

Now my question is can I somehow tunnel the HTTP traffic on `192.X.X.X` from `B` to `C` or is that even possible.

i.e., Can I open a browser on `C` type an IP and see the web app similar to how I would on `B`

Comment: This will almost certainly be a duplicate that has been asnwered a number of times before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `-L` argument to forward a local socket to a remote socket.

For example, run the following on Host C:

```bash
ssh -L "${LOCAL_PORT}:${REMOTE_HOST}:${REMOTE_PORT}" "${HOST_B}"
```

Then, on Host C, navigate to `http://localhost:${LOCAL_PORT}/` (or `https://` as appropriate).

If you need to access this service from another device on Host C's network, then you can also give the `-g` argument, which will allow other hosts to connect too (i.e: bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of the default `127.0.0.1`). Beware that this is unauthenticated, and may pose a security risk for your use-case. e.g:

```bash
ssh -gL "${LOCAL_PORT}:${REMOTE_HOST}:${REMOTE_PORT}" "${HOST_B}"
```

In the above examples, substitute the variables as follows:

- `${LOCAL_PORT}`: Pick a port above 1024 if you're unprivileged, picking a common port may cause issues with services already running on Host C
- `${REMOTE_HOST}`: Host A's IP or name
- `${REMOTE_PORT}`: The port of the service running on Host A